# Symfony QueryBuilder - Check if an array contains any item of another array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to find if an array contains any item another array. I tried the following but it does not works :

```
        $query
            ->innerJoin('company', 'c')
            ->where('c.numbers in (:numbers)')
            ->setParameter('numbers', $user->getNumbers());
```

Numbers is simply an array containing numbers like [1,2,3,4] (stored in DB as DC2Type:array) I use the same type in the two entities

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
private $numbers = [];
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Racsor. You say that it does not work. Can you provide us more information? Have you got a bug or data retrieved are different from what you expected? 
With the information your are providing, I don't understand why you're using a left join instead of an inner join and why you're using andWhere instead of where. You should provide us your metadata class.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Alexandre. I updated my post, in fact I tried with innerJoin and where too, but it does not work.. (I mean it does not return any result). For example the case : user numbers : [1,2,3] and company numbers [2,3] it should be true